# Several questions about CUDA and cuPrintf

Tags: cuda

1. I can compile successfully my code using cuPrintf by nvcc, but cannot compile it in Visual Studio 2012 environment. It says that "volatile char *" cannot be changed to "const void *" in "cudaMemcpyToSymbol" function.
2. cuPrintf seems doesn't work, there's no cuPrintf function executed in kernel code.
3. How to make nvcc export pdb file?
4. Is there any other convenient way to debug in kernel function? I have only one laptop.

Comment: can you post the nvcc compile line used in MSVC? And the code too

Comment: Can you put the compile flag to a higher architecture and try using regular printf?

Answer (score 1):

1st , cuPrinft is deprecated (As far as I know it has never been released) you can print data from kernel using print command, but this is a very not recommended way of debugging your kernels.

2nd, You are compiling using CUDA nvcc compiler, there is no such thing pdb file in CUDA, Albeit watch the 'g' and 'G' flags, those may dramatically increase your running time.

3rd, 
[The best way to debug kernels is using visual Nsight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition)

Comment: I need pdb file to debug host code, and compiling using VS can generate pdb file. I never use Visual Nsight successfully, that's why I find cuPrint. But thank you anyway.

Comment: cuPrintf is still part of the cuda sample [simple printf](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpleprintf) sample code in the current (cuda 5.5) released toolkit.  cuPrintf is used in that sample when cc < 2.0.  I'm not sure what deprecated means in this context.  It's a sample code.

Comment: Try to run nsight, it's really good debugger tool, worth the effort,  regarding to cuprinf, I would recommend using cc » 20, older versions than that would be old devices and lack of Programming options .